# If SQL_ collation is "used for backwards compatibility" why is it the default for new installations and Azure?

Tags: sql-server, collation

This is the screen you see when you're prompted to choose a Server-wide collation for a new installation of Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (using the latest ISO with SP1):

[image]

It says "SQL collation, used for backwards compatibility" - implying "Windows collation" is preferred - I also note Windows collation appears as the first radio button, so it should be preferred.

So if SQL Collation is legacy, why is it still the default for new installations of the latest SQL Server releases? What are the possible reasons for keeping it the default? Is there any reason to keep on using the SQL_ collation options? I note that Azure SQL is the same, and that also defaults to `SQL_Latin1_General_SP1_CI_AS` when you create a new database.

Comment: A **lot of code** is written with the assumption that the default SQL collation is used. So to maintain backwards compatibility, you need that or things like case sensitive string evaluation would be on and break lots of things. As for Azure, this is because the user can't access the underlying VM that runs SQL, so it needs to use database collation.